# PolyglotException: TypeError: instantiate on {Class} failed due to: Message not supported

Tags: karate

How do I troubleshoot this kind of error I am getting in Karate?

I was in the middle of refactoring and my project started failing with this error and I cannot find the typo.

Is there a way to turn on debugging (via logback-test.xml) for the graalvm polyglot stuff?   I just don't know what would cause this.   It seems to be related to the string arguments I am passing to my Java client class.

```
js failed:
>>>>
01: new QueueWriteClient(global.sb_namespace, global.sb_client_id, servicebus_key)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: instantiate on me.it.QueueWriteClient
 failed due to: Message not supported.
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

classpath:features/utils/queue_write.feature:31
```

NOTE: My Java class runs fine from it's `public static void main` method.   So, I am sure it has something to do with Karate calling the class.

My client is loaded like this:

```
* print doc
* print src
* def QueueWriteClient = Java.type('me.it.QueueWriteClient')
* def writer = new QueueWriteClient(global.sb_namespace, global.sb_client_id, servicebus_key)
* def result = writer.writeToQueue(doc, src)
```

When it says `Message not supported`, it seems to me that the error comes from graalvm code, concerning instantiation of Java class?

Comment: I agree this is hard to troubleshoot when it happens. my best guess is `me.it.QueueWriteClient` is not on the classpath

Comment: I'll try creating a basic test class that just prints the arguments and see if i can get that to work.   I've been writing Karate+Java tests for years now, so this is unusual for me.

Comment: yes, do share any findings. I vaguely remember running into this once and my workaround was to ensure that the class was constructed somehow on the "java side" instead of from karate. if it means using a static method on a helper class etc. try that. look out also if the constructor is `public` etc.

Comment: Thank you.  Good call outs, and things I haven't tried yet.  I'll let you know.

Comment: I burned a whole 1.5 days on that dumb error.   YES, the solution was marking the constructor public.    Any way Karate could detect that with human readable error?

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER/SOLUTION (from Peter Thomas):   mark Java class constructor public.   If Peter leaves an answer here, I will mark that one as the solution.

It also appears that a similar error can be thrown if a RuntimeException is thrown (such as a simple NullPointerException).  As you know, RuntimeException doesn't require that you handle it in Java code and so this scenario is also easy to miss.